# How to call a function defined in main ViewController from secondary view controller in swift without using delegates?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I call the playAgain() function which is defined in ViewController, from DisplayScoreController ?

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func playAgain() {
        print("Play Again")
    } 
}
```

DisplayScoreController.swift

```
class DisplayScoreController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    // I want to call playAgain() in ViewController
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by passing a closure to the `DisplayScoreController` that dismisses that controller and calls `playAgain()`.

In the example below, I set up that closure in `prepare(for:sender:)`.  If you aren't launching `DisplayScoreController` with a segue, you could assign this closure just after you instantiate the `DisplayScoreController` and before you present it.

In my example, I trigger the calling of the closure when the user has pressed the `Done` button in `DisplayScoreController`.  You could put the call to `self.goPlayAgain?()` anywhere you want to trigger that action.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func playAgain() {
        print("Play Again")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showScore" {
            if let dvc = segue.destination as? DisplayScoreController {
                // assign closure to goPlayAgain property
                // of destination view controller to dismiss
                // the destination and call playAgain()
                dvc.goPlayAgain = {
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.playAgain()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

class DisplayScoreController: UIViewController {

    // property to hold closure which dismisses this
    // view controller and calls playAgain() in
    // ViewController   
    var goPlayAgain: (() -> ())?

    // Time to return to ViewController and call playAgain()       
    @IBAction func done(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.goPlayAgain?()
    }

}
```

Comment: Aces, very nice and clean. I already had the prepare segue function to pass my variables, I just had to add the goPlayAgain part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call it a delegate, but that's the idea. You need a pointer to the object that has the `playAgain()` function. Defining a protocol and adding an instance var to your `DisplayScoreController` that points to an object that conforms to that protocol enables `DisplayScoreController` to send the `playAgain()` message to some other object.

You can call the object fred if you want to:

```
protocol PlayAgainProtocol {
      func playAgain() 
}


class DisplayScoreController: UIViewController {

  weak var fred: PlayAgainProtocol?

  @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    fred?.playAgain()
  }
}
```

The variable is named `fred` rather than `delegate`. Does that mean you're not using delegates? No, not really, but you aren't using the **term** delegate...

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, but I could not make it work with this approach. the function did not get called. I suppose you made an assumption that I am not aware of it.

Comment: Yes, when `ViewController` creates `DisplayScoreController`, it needs to set itself as fred. (Something like `theDisplayScoreController.fred = self`).

Comment: I was being a bit tongue and cheek. The above IS the delegate design pattern, just using `fred` rather than `delegate`.